# center align text in image using php

Tags: php

I am trying to do center align text in image using php, i have managed to make it right aligned properly but how can i make text center aligned... Please check code for right aligned text...

```
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

    $dimensions = imagettfbbox(24, 0, 'arial.ttf', 'Test Heading');
    $textWidth = abs($dimensions[4] - $dimensions[0]);
    $x = imagesx($image) - $textWidth - 20; //add -20 to give right margin
    imagefttext($image, 24, 0, $x, 40, $black, 'arial.ttf', 'Test Heading');
```

How can i make text center aligned, any help. thanks

Comment: left position: `((width of container / 2) - (width of text box / 2))`

Comment: @MarcB let me try your code quickly.

Comment: @MarcB it just worked, thanks for your help. :)